# Win32 Child Window Style Not Matching Parent

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am creating a child window for a VST3 plugin and am finding that the style of the child is different to the parent - in fact windows seems to be picking up an older rounded style from somewhere when I am on windows 10 which has the modern square style.

I don't have control over the parent window style. In this scenario an audio workstation hands me a HWND that I use as the parent handle in

```
 window->win32.handle = CreateWindowExW(exStyle,
                                       _GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME,
                                       wideTitle,
                                       style,
                                       xpos, ypos,
                                       fullWidth, fullHeight,
                                       parent_handle, 
                                       NULL, 
                                       GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                                       NULL);
```

I am using (a slightly modified - to accept a parent handle - and freshly compiled) version of GLFW to create the window.

Does anyone have an idea about where the style could be changing?

When I create the window as a parent window the correct style is applied. To create the child I am adding WS_CHILD to this. Digging out the exact style is hard because GLFW constructs it  in a sequence of functions.

As a Late Edit. It seems similar to this problem reported with MDI windows
where MDI child window styles don't match the parent style from wayyy back in Win7 - but still is being mentioned.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/34b29567-28a1-4aeb-97d2-d1476ba856f5/mdi-child-window-appearance?forum=vcgeneral

[image: Child Window Style]

Comment: Does the WindowProc in `_GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME` handle drawing the window frame?

Comment: Yes . And I have checked that it is being called.

Comment: I get handed the handle to the outer frame - FRED (for want of a better window name) is created by me

Comment: That's just what MDI child windows look like I think. MDI is basically deprecated so Microsoft did not bother updating their appearance for Win10.

Comment: problem is that I am not using mdi - just a similar situation.  Have tried a sample project that uses a different toolkit - and that works - although has other problems which is why I was looking at GLFW

Comment: The window styles GLFW are giving the window are intended for toplevel windows, not child windows. And there's a good reason: GLFW wasn't really designed to write plugins with; it was designed to write programs with, and thus expects you to create the application window with it rather than with another framework. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/25) asking for a way for GLFW to be integrated with other toolkits, but in the meantime you should investigate using wgl directly (or finding what framework the host process uses and using that).

Comment: I think I have found a way to do it - but still investigating. Essentially I need to expose the native window handle via GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32 to attach the window as a child - and then remove all decoration with the undecorated window hint glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GL_FALSE);   I still need to find a work around for the message pump - but if it works it means I can use the normal GLFW kit rather than my patched version

Comment: @BrentonThomas what does GLFW provide that you need to use?

Comment: GLFW provides cross platform opengl in the first instance as the main reason.  A GL context in its own right is not trivial - but can be done. But to properly provide an OpenGL ui also need mouse events, key events, drag drop etc etc etc.  To properly write a window procedure just for windows to do this is a big job. And then it has to be done on OSX as well.  whereas GLFW already provides a minimal cross platform OpenGL context with mouse and keyboard.